What to do with the "israel" tag?
There's an israel tag with 23 questions on it. At a quick glance, my impression is that most of them have to do with the State of Israel, and some have to do with the Land of Israel. This tag is redundant and ambiguous.
I see while I'm writing this (thanks, Similar Questions Bot!) that this is effectively a follow-up to Should we have a state-of-israel tag? . There, we removed israel as a synonym for eretz-yisrael because "Israel" in contemporary English refers more often to the State of Israel.
I propose that we now:

Move any questions tagged israel that are not about the State to the relevant other tag (most often eretz-yisrael).
Make israel a synonym of state-of-israel.


Perhaps blacklisting israel would be better.

@DoubleAA I could go either way. Synonimizing has the virtue of being easier to get done.

@IsaacMoses good opportunity to check the "state of Israel" questions are on topic

@RabbiKaii If you're asking whether it's possible to have on-topic questions about the State of Israel, justifying a tag with that name, the answer is "sure," with many examples linked in the post I linked to. If you're proposing cruising through the tag to see if there anything open that ought to be closed, feel free!

@IsaacMoses can't right now, but would be easier to do pre-merge, that's all. They can be on topic, but it's not guaranteed, like the "eretz-yisrael" tag is

@RabbiKaii Oh, you mean specifically for the ones currently tagged [israel]? Yes, if we implement this plan, someone will have to go through to see which ones need retagging, which would also naturally be a good time to check if  they need closure.
